# Apache Calcite, "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out" exception when executing a query which takes more than 3 minutes

Tags: jdbc, apache-calcite

I'm using Apache Calcite Data driver to connect to a remote datasource using plain jdbc. The connection is fine and i'm able to execute and retrieve data for a query which takes 3s. However the issue is when i want to execute a query which takes more than 3 minutes. During the later case i get "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out"
Connection url: jdbc:avatica:remote:url=http://host:port/druid/v2/sql/avatica/;http_connection_timeout=600000
maven dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.calcite.avatica</groupId>
            <artifactId>avatica-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Please note as per [Calcite documentation](https://calcite.apache.org/avatica/docs/client_reference.html), i have used http_connection_timeout and set the value to 10 minutes.

Below is the stacktrace of the error. Request you to please help to resolve the issue

```
2023-12-26 14:19:13.956 ERROR 28188 --- [nio-8821-exec-1] c.n.C.repository.SqlExecutorImpl         : Error while executing query: SELECT
  t."method_name",
  c."node_name",
  c."common_title",
  COUNT(t."self_duration") cnt,
  SUM(t."self_duration") sum_self_duration,
  MIN(t."self_duration") sum_self_duration,
  MAX(t."self_duration") sum_self_duration,
  AVG(t."self_duration") avg_self_duration,
  SUM(t."duration") sum_duration,
  MIN(t."duration") min_duration,
  MAX(t."duration") max_duration,
  AVG(t."duration") avg_duration
FROM
  "calls_mt" c,
  "trace_m" t
WHERE
  t."trace_id" = c."trace_id"
  AND c."params" IS NOT NULL
  AND c."params" [ 'web.url' ] [ 1 ] IS NOT NULL
  AND c."node_name" IN (
    'TMMD1-01',
    'TMMD1-02',
    'TMMD1-03',
    'TMMD1-04',
    'TMUI1-01',
    'TMUI1-02',
    'TMUI1-03',
    'TMUI1-04',
    'TMUI1-05',
    'TMUI1-06',
    'TMUI1-07',
    'TMUI1-08',
    'TMUI1-09',
    'TMUI1-10',
    'TMUI1-11',
    'TMUI1-12'
  )
  AND c.start_timestamp BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2023-12-14 11:16:29 UTC'
  AND TIMESTAMP '2023-12-14 12:20:33 UTC'
  AND t."method_name" LIKE '%ClientExceptionLogger.consoleDoServerLog%'
GROUP BY
  t."method_name",
  c."node_name",
  c."common_title" LIMIT 200

java.sql.SQLException: Error while executing SQL "SELECT
  t."method_name",
  c."node_name",
  c."common_title",
  COUNT(t."self_duration") cnt,
  SUM(t."self_duration") sum_self_duration,
  MIN(t."self_duration") sum_self_duration,
  MAX(t."self_duration") sum_self_duration,
  AVG(t."self_duration") avg_self_duration,
  SUM(t."duration") sum_duration,
  MIN(t."duration") min_duration,
  MAX(t."duration") max_duration,
  AVG(t."duration") avg_duration
FROM
  "calls_mt" c,
  "trace_m" t
WHERE
  t."trace_id" = c."trace_id"
  AND c."params" IS NOT NULL
  AND c."params" [ 'web.url' ] [ 1 ] IS NOT NULL
  AND c."node_name" IN (
    'TMMD1-01',
    'TMMD1-02',
    'TMMD1-03',
    'TMMD1-04',
    'TMUI1-01',
    'TMUI1-02',
    'TMUI1-03',
    'TMUI1-04',
    'TMUI1-05',
    'TMUI1-06',
    'TMUI1-07',
    'TMUI1-08',
    'TMUI1-09',
    'TMUI1-10',
    'TMUI1-11',
    'TMUI1-12'
  )
  AND c.start_timestamp BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2023-12-14 11:16:29 UTC'
  AND TIMESTAMP '2023-12-14 12:20:33 UTC'
  AND t."method_name" LIKE '%ClientExceptionLogger.consoleDoServerLog%'
GROUP BY
  t."method_name",
  c."node_name",
  c."common_title" LIMIT 200": java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:56) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:41) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaStatement.executeInternal(AvaticaStatement.java:164) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaStatement.executeQuery(AvaticaStatement.java:228) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at com.test.CallsDumperWeb.repository.SqlExecutorImpl.fetchData(SqlExecutorImpl.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.test.CallsDumperWeb.repository.SqlExecutorImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$91f85cf6.invoke(<generated>) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) [spring-core-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) [spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) [spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) [spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) [spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) [spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at com.test.CallsDumperWeb.repository.SqlExecutorImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$94250e9b.fetchData(<generated>) [classes/:na]
    at com.test.CallsDumperWeb.services.SQLServiceImpl.fetchData(SQLServiceImpl.java:30) [classes/:na]
    at com.test.CallsDumperWeb.controllers.SqlController.download(SqlController.java:91) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) [spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) [spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) [spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) [spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) [spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) [spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) [spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1787) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_202]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.AvaticaCommonsHttpClientImpl.send(AvaticaCommonsHttpClientImpl.java:143) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.RemoteService.apply(RemoteService.java:36) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.JsonService.apply(JsonService.java:140) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.RemoteMeta$14.call(RemoteMeta.java:310) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.RemoteMeta$14.call(RemoteMeta.java:307) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.invokeWithRetries(AvaticaConnection.java:795) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.RemoteMeta.fetch(RemoteMeta.java:306) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.MetaImpl$FetchIterator.moveNext(MetaImpl.java:1600) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.MetaImpl$FetchIterator.<init>(MetaImpl.java:1568) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.MetaImpl$FetchIterator.<init>(MetaImpl.java:1543) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.MetaImpl$FetchIterable.iterator(MetaImpl.java:1538) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.MetaImpl.createCursor(MetaImpl.java:97) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaResultSet.execute(AvaticaResultSet.java:186) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection$1.execute(AvaticaConnection.java:669) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.RemoteMeta$13.call(RemoteMeta.java:283) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.RemoteMeta$13.call(RemoteMeta.java:263) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.invokeWithRetries(AvaticaConnection.java:795) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.RemoteMeta.prepareAndExecute(RemoteMeta.java:262) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.prepareAndExecuteInternal(AvaticaConnection.java:677) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaStatement.executeInternal(AvaticaStatement.java:157) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:149) ~[httpcore5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280) ~[httpcore5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:241) ~[httpcore5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:53) ~[httpcore5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:298) ~[httpcore5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:175) ~[httpcore5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:218) ~[httpcore5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionEndpoint.execute(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:583) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.execute(InternalExecRuntime.java:212) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:105) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:182) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:175) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:96) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ContentCompressionExec.execute(ContentCompressionExec.java:133) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:115) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:170) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:75) ~[httpclient5-5.1.3.jar:5.1.3]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.AvaticaCommonsHttpClientImpl.execute(AvaticaCommonsHttpClientImpl.java:151) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.AvaticaCommonsHttpClientImpl.send(AvaticaCommonsHttpClientImpl.java:122) ~[avatica-core-1.23.0.jar:1.23.0]
    ... 87 common frames omitted
```

i have tried below approaches:

- set http_connection_timeout in connection url to 600000(10minutes)
- set connection.setNetworkTimeout to 600000(10minutes)
- set statement.setQueryTimeout to 600000(10minutes)

i expected the query to run take more than 3 minutes and return result but instead got "SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out"